# I have method name in java, with that method name how can I get the class name

Tags: java, spring, underscore-java

I want to retrieve the class name in the runtime, I have a method name declared inside the class, with the help of method name how can i retrieve the class name in java??

Exmaple:

```
public class DesktopTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    @Parameters("Browser")
    public void navigateToWebPage(String browser) {
        System.out.print("Testing Done");
    }
```

I have method name `"navigateToWebPage"` which will be passed from maven commands, how to get the class name with this info

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: From where?  Inside the function, you certainly know what the class name is.  Outside the function, how would you be in a position to need this?  There might be 19 classes with a method called `navigateToWebPage`.

Comment: If you need a class name, you can call `.getClass()` and then `.getName()` on the object.  But as Tim Roberts says this is not normally something you need to do.

Comment: @TimRoberts , in my case I have unique method names across whole project. So there is not duplication of method names in different classes.

Comment: But surely you recognize that the compiler doesn't know that.  And you don't know what methods might be used in libraries you import.

Comment: @markspace if you are inside any method and run getClass().getName() it will print the current class, i can understand that but my objective is to get the class name by passing the method name as a parameter

Comment: A method name does not exist globally.  It only exists as a method for some object.  If you have a `DesktopText` object, then you can ask about `obj.navigateToWebPage`.  But the bare name by itself does not exist.

Comment: @TimRoberts, My bad, how i missed this?. Thanks for your time Tim and making me to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
String className = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName();
```

It's a method name, but what do you think?

or another

```
String className = CommonFuntion.getClassName();
```

---

2023.08.19

Sorry to Late
Anyway, you can refer this

```
public static void main(){

TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

System.out.println("getName()      : " + testClass.getClass().getName());
System.out.println("getSimpleName()  : " + testClass.getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println("===========getMethods()===========");
for(Method method : testClass.getClass().getMethods()){
    System.out.println("method          : " + method.getName());
}
System.out.println("===========getFields()===========");
for(Field field : testClass.getClass().getFields()){
    System.out.println("field           : " + field.getName());
}
```

}

Comment: Is `getClassName()` a static method of class `CommonFuntion`?

Comment: I should update my answer .